# Unable to run application in Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have a Node.js application which runs correctly on localhost, but not in the Compute Engine VM. Here is a snippet:

```
try {
    gcloud = require('gcloud');
    var storage = gcloud.storage({ projectId: 'project-id' });
    var bucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket');
    bucket.file(src_file).createReadStream().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(src_file));
} catch (e) {
    e = 'Error loading required classes for gcloud: '+gcloud+ ':  '+e
    console.log(e)
    res.status(200).send(e);
}
```

When I run this code

> undefined: Error: /app/node_modules/gcloud/node_modules/hash-stream-validation/node_modules/sse4_crc32/build/Release/sse4_crc32.node: invalid ELF header

It looks like I'm not able to import the gcloud classes, but I can't understand why it works in localhost but not in the GCE server??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid ELF sounds like you uploaded from localhost or compiled in a different environment.  Those deps need to be compiled/configured on the Google server.  Did you follow [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/run-on-compute-engine)?

Comment: I've read the instructions for https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/run-on-compute-engine, but do I really need to do all this configuration just to deploy my app? What about this example: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore  In the "Structured data" example, "gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --set-default" command was sufficient to deploy the application to the GCE server.  I have installed this example and I was able to run it both on localhost and on GCE server with just this simple deploy command

Comment: @Kwame — there are different deployment mechanisms which require different amounts of configuration and provide different trade-offs. If you are using "gcloud preview app", you are using [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) which are running on GCE but a slightly more constrained environment. If you want to run on a raw GCE VM with more flexibility, it will take more work and configuration.

Comment: Thank you Misha. I've made some head way since my last comment. I found out that "Invalid ELF Header" is referring to "Executable and Linkable Format": https://community.oracle.com/thread/3749710 which has something to do with eclipse (my IDE), so i moved my code out of Eclipse, and I was able to upload it to GCE server, and require the appropriate gcloud classes without any errors now. The app is still not running, but I'm guessing thats a different issue. Thanks again.

Comment: @Kwame Hey I am having the exact same problem and I am using Sublime as my text editor and I am not sure what's causing it. Where did you move your code to?

Comment: @DynamoBooster I used TextMate.