# Q: HyperLedger fabric-starter-kit customisation

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have followed the basic [guide](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/starter/fabric-starter-kit/) for getting the HyperLedger fabric-starter-kit up and running which works perfectly. I cannot figure out how to successfully change the development directory of the app.js without causing an "invalid ELF header" error:

```
root@104efc36f09e:/user/env# node app
module.js:355
   Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
                           ^
Error: /user/env/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node: invalid ELF header
   at Error (native)
   at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
   at require (module.js:384:17)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/user/env/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/grpc_extension.js:38:15)
   at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
root@104efc36f09e:/user/env#
```

**Dockerfile** (unchanged):

```
FROM hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02
RUN go build
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/sdk/node
RUN npm install hfc`
```

**docker-compose.yaml** (changed volume to local workdir: ~/Documents/Work/Blockchain/env):

```
membersrvc:
  container_name: membersrvc
  image: hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc
  command: membersrvc

peer:
  container_name: peer
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
  environment:
    - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
    - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
    - CORE_PEER_ID=vp0
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=true
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_ECA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_TCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_TLSCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_PEER_VALIDATOR_CONSENSUS_PLUGIN=noops
  # this gives access to the docker host daemon to deploy chain code in network mode
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  # have the peer wait 10 sec for membersrvc to start
  #  the following is to run the peer in Developer mode - also set sample DEPLOY_MODE=dev
  command: sh -c "sleep 10; peer node start --peer-chaincodedev"
  #command: sh -c "sleep 10; peer node start"
  links:
    - membersrvc

starter:
  container_name: starter
  image: hyperledger/fabric-starter-kit
  volumes:
    - ~/Documents/Work/Blockchain/env:/user/env
  environment:
    - MEMBERSRVC_ADDRESS=membersrvc:7054
    - PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7051
    - KEY_VALUE_STORE=/tmp/hl_sdk_node_key_value_store
    # set to following to 'dev' if peer running in Developer mode
    - DEPLOY_MODE=dev
    - CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc
    - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7051
  # the following command will start the chain code when this container starts and ready it for deployment by the app
  command: sh -c "sleep 20; /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02/chaincode_example02"
  stdin_open: true
  tty: true
  links:
    - membersrvc
    - peer
```

**app.js** (unchanged):

```
/*
 * A simple application utilizing the Node.js Client SDK to:
 * 1) Enroll a user
 * 2) User deploys chaincode
 * 3) User queries chaincode
 */
// "HFC" stands for "Hyperledger Fabric Client"
var hfc = require("hfc");

console.log(" **** STARTING APP.JS ****");

// get the addresses from the docker-compose environment
var PEER_ADDRESS         = process.env.CORE_PEER_ADDRESS;
var MEMBERSRVC_ADDRESS   = process.env.MEMBERSRVC_ADDRESS;

var chain, chaincodeID;

// Create a chain object used to interact with the chain.
// You can name it anything you want as it is only used by client.
chain = hfc.newChain("mychain");

// Initialize the place to store sensitive private key information
chain.setKeyValStore( hfc.newFileKeyValStore('/tmp/keyValStore') );

// Set the URL to membership services and to the peer
console.log("member services address ="+MEMBERSRVC_ADDRESS);
console.log("peer address ="+PEER_ADDRESS);
chain.setMemberServicesUrl("grpc://"+MEMBERSRVC_ADDRESS);
chain.addPeer("grpc://"+PEER_ADDRESS);

// The following is required when the peer is started in dev mode
// (i.e. with the '--peer-chaincodedev' option)
var mode =  process.env['DEPLOY_MODE'];
console.log("DEPLOY_MODE=" + mode);
if (mode === 'dev') {
    chain.setDevMode(true);xs
    //Deploy will not take long as the chain should already be running
    chain.setDeployWaitTime(10);
} else {
    chain.setDevMode(false);
    //Deploy will take much longer in network mode
    chain.setDeployWaitTime(120);
}


chain.setInvokeWaitTime(10);

// Begin by enrolling the user
enroll();

// Enroll a user.
function enroll() {
   console.log("enrolling user admin ...");
   // Enroll "admin" which is preregistered in the membersrvc.yaml
   chain.enroll("admin", "Xurw3yU9zI0l", function(err, admin) {
      if (err) {
         console.log("ERROR: failed to register admin: %s",err);
         process.exit(1);
      }
      // Set this user as the chain's registrar which is authorized to register other users.
      chain.setRegistrar(admin);

      var userName = "JohnDoe";
      // registrationRequest
      var registrationRequest = {
          enrollmentID: userName,
          affiliation: "bank_a"
      };
      chain.registerAndEnroll(registrationRequest, function(error, user) {
          if (error) throw Error(" Failed to register and enroll " + userName + ": " + error);
          console.log("Enrolled %s successfully\n", userName);
          deploy(user);
      });      
   });
}

// Deploy chaincode
function deploy(user) {
   console.log("deploying chaincode; please wait ...");
   // Construct the deploy request
   var deployRequest = {
       chaincodeName: process.env.CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME,
       fcn: "init",
       args: ["a", "100", "b", "200"]
   };
   // where is the chain code, ignored in dev mode
   deployRequest.chaincodePath = "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02";

   // Issue the deploy request and listen for events
   var tx = user.deploy(deployRequest);
   tx.on('complete', function(results) {
       // Deploy request completed successfully
       console.log("deploy complete; results: %j",results);
       // Set the testChaincodeID for subsequent tests
       chaincodeID = results.chaincodeID;
       invoke(user);
   });
   tx.on('error', function(error) {
       console.log("Failed to deploy chaincode: request=%j, error=%k",deployRequest,error);
       process.exit(1);
   });

}

// Query chaincode
function query(user) {
   console.log("querying chaincode ...");
   // Construct a query request
   var queryRequest = {
      chaincodeID: chaincodeID,
      fcn: "query",
      args: ["a"]
   };
   // Issue the query request and listen for events
   var tx = user.query(queryRequest);
   tx.on('complete', function (results) {
      console.log("query completed successfully; results=%j",results);
      process.exit(0);
   });
   tx.on('error', function (error) {
      console.log("Failed to query chaincode: request=%j, error=%k",queryRequest,error);
      process.exit(1);
   });
}

//Invoke chaincode
function invoke(user) {
   console.log("invoke chaincode ...");
   // Construct a query request
   var invokeRequest = {
      chaincodeID: chaincodeID,
      fcn: "invoke",
      args: ["a", "b", "1"]
   };
   // Issue the invoke request and listen for events
   var tx = user.invoke(invokeRequest);
   tx.on('submitted', function (results) {
          console.log("invoke submitted successfully; results=%j",results);       
       });   
   tx.on('complete', function (results) {
      console.log("invoke completed successfully; results=%j",results);
      query(user);      
   });
   tx.on('error', function (error) {
      console.log("Failed to invoke chaincode: request=%j, error=%k",invokeRequest,error);
      process.exit(1);
   });
}
```

My goal is to create an authentication service using the HFC so that an Android app invoke a transaction. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you switching between the platforms or the architecture for the development ? make sure that `npm` modules are built on the platform you are executing it. Try re-installing your node modules. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618976/nodejs-google-compute-engine-invalid-elf-header-when-using-gcloud-module and this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994411/invalid-elf-header-when-using-the-nodejs-ref-module-on-aws-lambda . let me know if it helps

Comment: @SufiyanGhori Great help! I deleted the node_modules folder in my work directory and ran `npm install hfc@0.6.x` from inside the `starter` docker image which worked. Thanks!

Comment: try to use this boilerplate https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/fabric-boilerplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you installed node modules in your mac and used them in your Linux docker image. This is what causing the problem.

Make sure that `npm` modules are built on the platform you are executing it. Re-install your node modules in your linux environment by first deleting `node_modules` and running `npm install` from inside `starter` docker image.

Please consult these questions as well,

[NodeJs Google Compute Engine Invalid ELF Header when using 'gcloud' module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618976/nodejs-google-compute-engine-invalid-elf-header-when-using-gcloud-module)

["invalid ELF header" when using the nodejs "ref" module on AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994411/invalid-elf-header-when-using-the-nodejs-ref-module-on-aws-lambda)

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Sufiyan Ghori for pointing this out - the issue was that the node modules were installed in my host (mac) and therefore weren't compatible with the linux docker image I was trying to execute code within.

SOLUTION:

- Delete `node_modules` folder from work directory.
- Run `npm install hfc@0.6.x` from inside the `starter` docker image.